# Is there a way for google colab to take in a .vimrc file?

Tags: google-colaboratory

This question is about the "Editor Keybind: Vim" mode of colab,
I am too used to typing `j` twice to exit the edit mode in regualr vim. All I need is that one simple binding. It would be nice if colab could "take in" a one-liner .vimrc file containing:

```
imap jj <Esc>
```

One way or annother, is `jj` to `<Esc>` binding possible in colab?

Comment: if you run any command with `!` in google colab, it will run as terminal i.e. `!pip intsall -u pip`

Comment: @tard WOW! it WORKS, thanks!
well, more like the `:` key, but god, this colab thing is good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have not found out how to let colab take in a .vimrc file, but I did get the answer of how to map `jj` to `<Esc>` in colab

while in normal mode (the bottom right corner of the cell you are working on, it should display `--NORMAL--`), type in `:`, and your cursor will be moved to a text field at the bottom your cell, now you are in "command" mode. type in:

```
imap jj <Esc>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you run any command with `!` or `:` in google colab, it will run as terminal i.e. `!pip intsall -u pip` [example](https://i.postimg.cc/dVMqzjMg/Screenshot-2021-09-18-at-9-54-31-PM.png)

Comment: not the `!` mode, more like the `:` mode, because it is not a system's command, but vim's own command. so the way to do this is `: imap jj <Esc>`