# Remap 'jk' to <ESC> in Google Colab Vim

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am using the vim keybindings in the Google Colab editor. However I want to remap 'jk' to  in the Insert mode, similar to the result of `inoremap jk <ESC>` in `.vimrc`. How do I make this change?

Comment: See related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69236097/is-there-a-way-for-google-colab-to-take-in-a-vimrc-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

press escape to switch normal mode then press : to switch to command mode then type

```
:imap jk <Esc>
```